# How to keep the real width rate of the thumbnails on facebook share.php

Tags: facebook, thumbnails

I'm trying to use share.php and I already have some thumbnails on the site. Some of these thumbs are wide and when I try to share it on FB by share.php (p[images][0]) the FB popup cut the thumb to display the thumb. There is a way to avoid this behavior?

On my searchs I see that the best wasy is to have square images.

[image]

I would like to do something like this image below:
[image]

There is any way to do this?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Well, just to update. I decided to use [FB.ui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) 

Btw... tks @Bruno Barreto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To not have your images resized (or avoid big cuts), you'll need to use images with 1.91:1 aspect ratio and at least 1200x630 pixels.

There is more information here on item 4: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/howtos/maximizing-distribution-media-content/

As you already have many posts/articles in your website, you can use a script like timthumb (https://code.google.com/p/timthumb/) to generate a resized thumbnail with borders when the image is not in that aspect ratio.